# Why this iteration doesn't change correctly the global DF Variable

Tags: pandas, dataframe, loops

I have a similar code from the one below for my job and I don't know why it doesn't change correctly the global DF variables by a nested array for loop.

```py
>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({
>>  'x': [1,2,3,4,5],
>>  'y': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>> })
>> df2 = df1

>> for array in [[df1, 9], [df2, 'z']]:
>>  array[0]['x'] = array[1]
>>  array[0]['y'] = array[1]
>>  print(array[0])

   x  y
0  9  9
1  9  9
2  9  9
3  9  9
4  9  9
   x  y
0  z  z
1  z  z
2  z  z
3  z  z
4  z  z

>> print(df1)
   x  y
0  z  z
1  z  z
2  z  z
3  z  z
4  z  z
>> print(df2)
   x  y
0  z  z
1  z  z
2  z  z
3  z  z
4  z  z
```

So in the first iteration we see the correct changes, df1 with 9 in both columns and df2 with z in both columns.
But then when we check the global variables we see everything as z, even the df1. And I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an object in python is mutable, you copy by reference and not by value. For example; `int` and `str` are immutable object types, but `list`, `dict` and `pandas.DataFrame` are mutable. See the below example for `int` and `list` what this means:

```
a = 1
b = a
b += 1
print(a)
# >> 1

x = [1,2,3]
y = x
y.append(4)
print(x)
# >> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

So, when you assigned `df2`, you assigned it to the exact same object as where `df1` was referring to. That means, that when you change `df2`, you also change the object that is referred to by `df1`, because it is physically the same object. You can check this by using the inbuilt `id()` function:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,2,3,4,5],  'y': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']})
df2 = df1
print(id(df1), id(df2))
# >> 4695746416 4695746416
```

To have a **new** copy of the same dataframe, you need to use `copy()`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,2,3,4,5],  'y': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']})
df2 = df1.copy()
print(id(df1), id(df2))
# >> 4695749728 4695742816
```